# Add a view-modes tag

Tags: discussion

Add a view-modes tag, there are [lots of questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=view+modes) about the subject. [Here are the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) for new tags:

> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always
>   favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a
>   strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else
>   has asked about before on this site.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion, do you have any immediate examples of questions it should be added to? If we do any mass-update on this we should be careful to distinguish between view modes and form modes (we can create a tag for the latter too if it looks necessary)

Comment: Most of what comes up during a [site search](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=view+modes) seem to apply to view modes. I've since earned the rep to create tags and created one. I can't bulk edit questions to add the tags though, since my rep isn't high enough for that.

Comment: That search result cannot be used to prove the tag is needed. First, [the search should be changed to just return questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+view+modes). (We don't tag a question with [tag:views] just because one of the answers says how to achieve a task with a view when the question was asking how to achieve a task with code for a custom module.)

Comment: Even the search link I used in the previous comment cannot be used as proof the tag is needed, since in that search page I can find a question containing the following sentences: _I created a simple content type and a form **mode** for this content type. Where can I **view** this form **mode** after creating it? I see no option for form **modes** when creating a content type._ (I highlighted the same words the search page highlights.)

Comment: Plus, there are questions where *view modes* appears in the question body, but the question is not really about view modes. (I can imagine a question saying _I even tried changing the  view mode settings, but I still have the same issue._)